# Cross referencing the attributes of nested class instance from the owner class instance

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I am new in pyhton.
I try to write a simple identity card reader and editor.
I created a window class using tkinter and a Character class which reads a card and displays the card and allow editing.
I simplified the code and removed many parts. Because anything works but I can not find a way to refer eachother's attributes of both instances from one to the other.
I want to keep both class separate. I know it is possible to inherit window class attributes to Character. But i don't want it.

### Here is the simplified code.

```
import tkinter

class CreateWindow :

    def __init__(self, width):
        self.width=width
        self.myCharacter=None
        self.CharacterLoaded=False
        self.CreateChar()


    def CreateChar (self):
        self.myCharacter=Character("George")


    def CheckMyList (self):
        print (CharacterLoaded)
        for i in self.myCharacter.Mylist:
            print(i)

class Character :


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.Mylist=[2,3,4,5,6]
        print ("Character created")
        MainWindow.CharacterLoaded=True
        MainWindow.CheckMyList()

MainWindow=CreateWindow(600)
```

---

Error : 
NameError: name 'MainWindow' is not defined
Character created

MainWindow is a instance of CreateWindow class and it will only be one instance during whole session . But each file will create and a new instance of Character class in MainWindow Class.

How to use such cross references ?

Comment: But you haven't created anything called MainWindow at all.

Comment: I removed the window configuration part cause it works Daniel. Otherwise code will be so long.Ony this cross referencing is not working ..It is the problem.. I can not call the methods of MainWindow from character instance so window class will be aware of attributes of Character and display it .. Then call the Character instance and make it to be saved .

Comment: Sorry MainWindow=CreateWindow(600) is creating an instance...

Comment: But where is that code?

Comment: Oh sorry Daniel I fixed it ..This is my first question so i just learn how to mark up the code.

Answer (score 0):

> MainWindow is a instance of CreateWindow class and it will only be one instance during whole session . But each file will create and a new instance of Character class in MainWindow Class.

If I understood you correctly, you just don't need to keep the `Character` instance inside the `MainWindow`.

You have one global `MainWindow` instance across the application and in other modules, you can do something like this:

```
from main_window import MainWindow

character = Character('this module')
MainWindow.CheckMyList(character)
```

Another module:

```
from main_window import MainWindow

character = Character('that module')
MainWindow.CheckMyList(character)
```

And the `CheckMyList` will, accordingly look like this:

```
def CheckMyList (self, character):
    for i in character.Mylist:
        print(i)
```

Or, vice versa it can be a `Character` class method and you'll pass the window instance into it.

Side note: check the python style guide (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), your way to format python code is very uncommon for python.

Comment: Thank you Boris i will check it .